# Bash String extraction

Tags: bash

I have a really easy problem that I am not able to solve quickly.  I must extract a substring from something like this:

```
a="www.himom.com/byebye"
```

I want to retrieve this:

```
"/byebye"
```

Actually, I am able to retrieve

"www.himom.com" with

```
echo ${a%/*}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
`echo /${a##*/}`
It deletes the longest substring ending at '/'.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 a="www.himom.com/byebye"; echo "/${a##*/}"
```

Comment: You will be missing the '/' character that he wants to get.

Comment: @izomorphius:  Maybe the poster edited the answer, but what I see worked on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

To leave the slash in the string

```
shopt -s extglob
echo "${a##*([^/])}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a lazy guy..  Solution was:

```
${a##*/}
```

Comment: Sorry for the multiple edits/rollbacks.  I tried to get the code to show correctly, but what I tried didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ a="www.himom.com/byebye" | echo ${a##*m}
/byebye
```

Answer (score -1):

You can extract your desired substring with a regex:

```
a="www.himom.com/byebye"
echo `expr match "$a" '.*\(\/.*\)'`
```